# Gnuplot: How to plot the sum of the previous residual to the next residual till (n-1) summs (desired plot values) of my (n) residuals?

Tags: function, plot, gnuplot

I have this residuals   .conv file (like a .txt file):

```
        0     -3.39778780952e+00     -3.64444458026e+00     -6.13098312717e+00     -3.33731379258e+00      9.60958415473e-02
        1     -5.68002563742e+00     -5.05666214505e+00     -6.80071922409e+00     -5.04462782788e+00      2.22031207076e-03
        2     -5.64107082704e+00     -4.97249772797e+00     -6.79863961158e+00     -4.96268354902e+00      2.61811084403e-03
        3     -5.80553774139e+00     -5.92252773129e+00     -8.00308750495e+00     -5.70572702588e+00      4.58014609089e-04
        4     -5.78806459727e+00     -6.01639219099e+00     -8.59850185227e+00     -5.72299102224e+00      3.93884617760e-04
        5     -6.81638698130e+00     -6.73802955972e+00     -8.62025323625e+00     -6.62315587350e+00      8.89255543212e-05
        6     -6.51291720873e+00     -6.69293919422e+00     -8.66002661220e+00     -6.43426100314e+00      1.09754466079e-04
        7     -7.57778891780e+00     -7.00314649895e+00     -8.63923998027e+00     -6.98816143858e+00      5.94338661679e-05
        8     -7.56036077709e+00     -7.01274467096e+00     -8.62954759664e+00     -6.99585319125e+00      5.69443692058e-05
```

and i want to plot in GNUPLOT, the 1st column with a new column (or not if it doesnt need to make a new one)  that would sum the previous value of the 6th column residual to the next residual of the **6th** column  and so on till i have (n-1) summs (desired plot values) of the **6th** column values in order to get the final deformation of each iteration.

For example as i sum the 6th column values: **9.60e10-2 + 2.22e10-3** --> *1st value of my desired column data*
**9.60e10-2 + 2.22e10-3 + 2.22e10-3** --> *2nd value of my desired column data*
and so on

I think i need a function to plot this for GNUPLOT.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code you plot the sum up a column. I guess it comes close to what I understood from your question. However, 1st value will be 1st row, 2nd value will be 1st+2nd row, 3rd value will be 1st+2nd+3d row, etc.  I hope you can modify it to your needs.

**Code:**

```
### sum up a column
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0     -3.39778780952e+00     -3.64444458026e+00     -6.13098312717e+00     -3.33731379258e+00      9.60958415473e-02
1     -5.68002563742e+00     -5.05666214505e+00     -6.80071922409e+00     -5.04462782788e+00      2.22031207076e-03
2     -5.64107082704e+00     -4.97249772797e+00     -6.79863961158e+00     -4.96268354902e+00      2.61811084403e-03
3     -5.80553774139e+00     -5.92252773129e+00     -8.00308750495e+00     -5.70572702588e+00      4.58014609089e-04
4     -5.78806459727e+00     -6.01639219099e+00     -8.59850185227e+00     -5.72299102224e+00      3.93884617760e-04
5     -6.81638698130e+00     -6.73802955972e+00     -8.62025323625e+00     -6.62315587350e+00      8.89255543212e-05
6     -6.51291720873e+00     -6.69293919422e+00     -8.66002661220e+00     -6.43426100314e+00      1.09754466079e-04
7     -7.57778891780e+00     -7.00314649895e+00     -8.63923998027e+00     -6.98816143858e+00      5.94338661679e-05
8     -7.56036077709e+00     -7.01274467096e+00     -8.62954759664e+00     -6.99585319125e+00      5.69443692058e-05 
EOD

plot s=0 $Data u 1:(s=s+$6) w lp pt 7 title "Sum up"

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to make a cumulative plot, like this:

[image: example plot]

It was generated by:

```
plot[1:][0.095:] 'temp.dat' u 1:6 smooth cumulative w p ps 2 lw 2 notitle
```

but the key is `smooth cumulative`.